# How to add a second domain to Kerio

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, email-server, kerio

We're running Kerio MailServer 6.7 and Apple OS X Server 10.5. I was wondering if it is possible to add a second domain to the mail server. Currently the mail server is on "examplemail.com" we would like to eventually move this to "mail.exampleserver.com".

The problem is that users already have the old server address in their email client and it will take time to change this but if we can somehow slowly move users to the new address that would be better. I can see were to add the domain under Kerio (Configuration->Domains) but I feel like there is more to it that this.

I'm not really sure what the best approach is for something like this.

Thanks, 
Aaron

Comment: Likely duplicate question: http://serverfault.com/questions/156674/mail-server-dns-question

Answer (score 1):

Once the MX entries are in place and correct, you should set a domain alias (mail.examplemail.com) to the examplemail.com. This way, mails will be delivered for both user@examplemail.com and user@mail.examplemail.com (if that is the primary domain, user authentication won't change, requiring only the username). When happy and sure that every client is updated, rename the domain to mail.examplemail.com, restart the server and delete the now-alias examplemail.com.

As reference: http://manuals.kerio.com/connect/adminguide/en/sect-domrename.html for renaming and http://manuals.kerio.com/connect/adminguide/en/sect-domalias.html for aliases.

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

For what you are describing, I don't believe you would want to add a second domain.  A second domain on Kerio will require another set of user accounts to be created, for their data to be migrated, and for all other settings to manually be replicated in the new domain.  I believe you should be able to rename the current domain in the Kerio Administration Console to the new domain name after creating and testing a CNAME record in DNS directing examplemail.com to mail.exampleserver.com.

The only problem with this will relate to SSL access.  They will get a domain name mismatch warning with their client (Outlook, web browser), but the data will still be encrypted.

If your Kerio mail server runs on Linux, you might be able to do something clever with symlinks to trick the server into working as both domains while sharing the same data directory.

Comment: Thanks Aaron for your advice on this. We've just upgraded to the newest Kerio Connect. Under domains, I have the option to add local domain or distributed domain. The domain that we're talking about is really a sub-domain of the Primary one that is listed in that Domain window. What do you think I should do?

Comment: Honestly, we stopped using Kerio right before it went to Connect but I am pretty sure distributed domain is for supporting multiple mail stores for one domain name.  (That's not what you are trying to do here.)